# Button Application- iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, button, sdk

I am a meganoob in iPhone Application programming.

All I want to do is make an application with a single button. When you press the button, it plays an audio file.

The button is just two images, one for the normal state and one for the pressed state.

I have no clue how to get from point A to point B, it seems so straightforward in web design, why can't it be like that for this too?

Anyone out there willing to drop some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone development is nothing like web design. Nearly all programming is not like web design, for that matter.

Start with a [good introduction to iPhone development](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/iphone_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide).

To answer this specific question, once you have learned the basics of iPhone development, you might look at the [Audio Session](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH1-SW1) portion of the SDK. You'll know how to hook up actions to buttons at this point, such as a *play* action for an audio file.

Answer (score 2):

Then do this as a web app.  Seriously.  Originally, that was Apple's solution to writing all apps for the iPhone.  They gave it an HTML 5 browser and wanted people to design custom web pages.  So if you can do this on the web (BTW: I could not but could do this in Objective-C in little time), do it that way.

You can create a link to your web page on the homescreen so it looks like an app.

Answer (score 1):

start from hello world for iPhone dude